# How to pass listview onClick events to parent view

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview inside a RelativeLayout. I want any clicks on the listview to call the Relativelayout's onClick listener. How can the listview pass it's click events to the parent view.

I tried this not working.

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        // Setting on Touch Listener for handling the touch inside
        // ScrollView
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of
            // child view
            listView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use one of those methods in order to be able to intercept the event before it gets sent to the appropriate components:

`Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` - This allows your Activity to intercept all touch events before they are dispatched to the window.

`ViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` - This allows a ViewGroup to watch events as they are dispatched to child Views.

`ViewParent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean)` - Call this upon a parent View to indicate that it should not intercept touch events with onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent).'

for reference please check here [EventHandlers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html#EventHandlers)

Answer (score 0):

Can use in XML:

```
 android:focusable="false"
```

In java code use:

```
 v.setClickable(false)
```